# ¿Porque la recursividad no es eficiente?

Tags: java

Necesito el factorial de 100, me doy cuenta que necesito buscar otra alternativa, podrian ayudar?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(factorial(100));
    }

    public static long factorial(long num) {        
        if (num <= 1) 
            return num;

        return num * factorial(num-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @x-rw la edición a forma recursiva la debe realizar OP, no nosotros.

Comment: Y por cierto factorial(100) es un número muy grande (9.332621544 E+157), no va a entrar en un long jamás

Comment: Creo que la pregunta está mal formulada, no significa que la recursividad no sea eficiente, sino que el factorial de 100 es un número grande incapaz de entrar en un long como bien dice @CarlosMuñoz

Comment: Y tendria que hacerlo  imperativamente? con ciclos y condiciones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema de la recursión surge cuando hace cálculos ya calculados previamente, la recursión calcula y repite calculos hasta llegar al caso base.

**Mejor lo explico con una imagen, el factorial(3) y el factorial(4) con recursividad:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun la imagen, para obtener el `factorial(3)` se calcula el `factorial(2)` y `factorial(1)`, luego para obtener el `factorial(4)` tambien calcula  el `factorial(2)` y `factorial(1)`, entonces la recursividad repite calculos, eso es muy malo para **tiempos de ejecucion**.

¿Por qué no guardar los resultados y usarlos cuando necesite? Asi ya no se calcularán una y otra vez, solamente calculas una vez y listo.

> El codigo que expongo solamente calcula una vez y va guardandolos,
>   para cuando necesite, de esa manera no vuelvo a calcular una y otra
>   vez.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(100));
    }

    public static double  factorial(int  n) {
        double  result[]=new double  [1000] ;          
                result[0] = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
                    result[i] = i * result[i - 1];
                }
                return result[n];
    }
}
```

segun comentarios, buenas observaciones!!!:

> Iterativo o recursivo el problema que mencionas se daría de todas
>   formas y que por cierto no aplica en este caso. De nada sirve
>   almacenar los resultados intermedios si luego se van a descartar todos
>   excepto el último

```
import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Main {
      double  result[]=new double  [1000] ;
      public Main(){
         result[0] = 1;
      }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(factorial(100));
        }

        public static double  factorial(int  n) {

                    if(!result[n]){
                     for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
                        result[i] = i * result[i - 1];
                     }
                     return result[n];
                    }else{
                      return result[n];
                    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Memoization....

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza J  exactamente + programacion dinamica,

Comment: No me parece programación dinámica por completo, solo la parte de memoization a medio camino.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza J en realidad no quise tocar el tema, creo que esta bien aplicado la PD, talves no se vea asi porque es algo sencillo.

Comment: pero en el caso del factorial, solamente esta multiplicando cada numero por el anterior una vez.. o me perdi de algo. el problema esta en busqueda de caminos. la explicacion del problema de memoization es buena.. la solucion en este caso viene por otro lado.

Comment: Iterativo o recursivo el problema que mencionas se daría de todas formas y que por cierto no aplica en este caso. De nada sirve almacenar los resultados intermedios si luego se van a descartar todos excepto el último.

Answer (score 8):

El problema no es la recursividad sino que el valor del factorial de 100 es demasiado grande para entrar en los bits de un `long`, ya sea en Java u otro lenguaje de programación que maneje este tipo de dato. Nótese que el valor máximo de un `long` en Java es `0x7fffffffffffffffL` o 9223372036854775807

En Java, esto se puede resolver usando `BigInteger`, aunque reduce el rendimiento de la aplicación.

Ejemplo:

```
public BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    return (n < 0) ? new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n)) :
        (n == 0 || n == 1) ? BigInteger.ONE :
        new BigInteger(
                String.valueOf(n))
            .multiply( factorial(n-1) );
}
```

Resultado:

```
System.out.println(factorial(100));
//imprime 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Falla para n = 0

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz corregido usando la misma lógica del OP

Comment: 0! == 1, tu código arroja 0

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz no lo he hecho formal, solo lo deje con la lógica del OP.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ no respondes la pregunta, ¿Porque la recursividad no es eficiente?

Comment: @x-rw "El problema no es la recursividad sino que el valor del factorial de 100 es demasiado grande para entrar en los bits de un `long`"...

Answer (score 2):

El código iterativo ya lo tenías tu mismo, solo hacía falta cambiar el tipo de dato de long a `double` ya que el factorial que buscabas es demasiado grande para `long`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(factorial(100));
    }

    public static double factorial(double num) {
       double suma = 1; 

       while(num > 1) {
           suma *= num;
           num --;
       }

       return suma;
    }
}
```

Eso devuelve: `9.332621544394418E157`

Comment: Gracias ya entiendo

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz no respondes la pregunta, ¿Porque la recursividad no es eficiente?